# Strange behaviour when drawing Lines vs. Rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line, scaletransform

Alright, how do I start this?

I have an application which is able to draw some shapes (actually it's a few thousand) on the screen. There are two types of them: Rectangles and Lines. Rectangles have a Fill, Lines have a Stroke + StrokeThickness.

I read data from two files, one has the data for the top side, one for the bottom side. To display the data, I use a Viewbox with a Canvas inside (so the contents are nicely stretched). The whole thing on the display looks like this (this is correct):

[image: Top on Screen]
[image: Bottom on Screen]

Now the very same application is supposed to print this image to a Printer (for testing I use the XPS Printer that comes with Windows).

When I print it (code follows), it gives for top the very same drawing, but for bottom the following:

[image: Bottom on Printout]

It looks like all "lines" are missing (the rectangles exist). To display the bottom, I use a scale transform with -1/-1 (mirror it horizontally as well as vertically). If I set the scale transform to 1/1 I get the following:

[image: Bottom - Non mirrored]

Now I am stuck. Why do all the lines disappear, but they are there if it's not mirrored. Also the outermost rectangle is a little bit shifted (this could be due to the data, so please don't focus on that).

The code that I use for drawing on screen is:

```
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" RenderTransform="{Binding RenderTransform}" Margin="20" Name="VwBox">
                <Viewbox.RenderTransformOrigin>
                    <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5"></Point>
                </Viewbox.RenderTransformOrigin>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Drawing}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTypeTemplateSelector}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas Width="{Binding DrawingWidth}" Height="{Binding DrawingHeight}">
                            </Canvas>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Viewbox>
```

For printing I do not rely on XAMl, but do it manually (it doesn't change a thing if I use the ContentPresenter or not):

```
                if (gs is GerberLine)
            {                   
                ContentPresenter cp = new ContentPresenter();
                var line = new Line();
                Canvas.SetLeft(cp, gs.Left);
                Canvas.SetTop(cp, gs.Top);
                line.X1 = 0.0;
                line.Y1 = 0.0;
                line.X2 = gs.Width;
                line.Y2 = gs.Height;
                line.Stroke = gs.Brush;
                line.StrokeThickness = ((GerberLine)gs).StrokeThickness;
                cp.Content = line;
                c.Children.Add(cp);
            }
            if (gs is GerberRect)
            {
                var r = new Rectangle();
                Canvas.SetLeft(r, gs.Left);
                Canvas.SetTop(r, gs.Top);
                r.Width = gs.Width;
                r.Height = gs.Height;
                r.Fill = gs.Brush;
                c.Children.Add(r);
            }
```

It looks like the lines do only disappear as soon as I mirror it horizontally since the top view is always correct (and it is mirrored vertically as well).

Any ideas? I'll be happy to elaborate if something is unclear. I think it has something to do with the scale transform, but I don't understand how (also why does it work on screen then?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would try:

1. Maybe the XPS driver in particular does not like the negative scaling.  Test with a different printer (PDF output or a real printer).
2. Use Rotate(180) instead of Scale(-1,-1).
3. After building your target document for print, rasterize it with [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) , save the resulting bitmap, and see if that looks as expected.
4. Create a minimal Gerber model and send that through the XPS code path.  Rename the .xps to .zip, and inspect the XML directly (it will be in `Documents\1\Pages\1.fpage` or something similar).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this first thing in the evening. Regarding #2 - I have tried that already, the result was the same.

Comment: Oh this is so very very very very wrong. Tested output to PDF: Works as expected, tested output to (a real) printer: works as expected. Sorry for bothering, was working on this for 3 nights.

Comment: Happy to help.  So, just to be clear, it sounds like the WPF content is not being encoded correctly to XPS, or the XPS Viewer is not rendering it correctly.

Comment: That thing gets funnier with every minute: This issue does not only appear for a single project but for every project (and it's always the bottom side). What's even more funny is that if I take the XPS (the one which doesn't display the lines) and if I print it out (either to PDF or my printer) the lines appear from nowhere.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is isolated to the XPS Viewer.

Comment: Yes .. and only to the viewer part of the viewer. Anyway, done. :)